# why binding Object shorthand property function is not a constructor when using with bind?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constructor, bind

```js
 var workshop = {
      teacher: "Kyle",
      ask: function (questioin) {   // not shorthand
        console.log(this.teacher, questioin);
      },
    };
    
new (workshop.ask.bind(workshop)); //"no problem runs fine."
```

but the below cause **TypeError: workshop.ask.bind(...) is not a constructor**

```js
 var workshop = {
      teacher: "Kyle",
      ask(questioin) {   //  shorthand
        console.log(this.teacher, questioin);
      },
    };
    
new (workshop.ask.bind(workshop)); // "this will give typeError";
```

Comment: It's simply defined by the language: Method definitions cannot be constructors. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#method_definitions_are_not_constructable

Comment: Even if it worked, using the `new` operator together with `bind` doesn't make any sense. The whole point of `bind` (at least when only using the first argument, which is the most common use) is to set the function's `this` to a particular object. Yet when using `new` you want the newly-constructed object to be the `this`.

Comment: couldn't agree more @RobinZigmond, but i was reading YDNKJ to observe the 'this' binding precedence.

Comment: This is not related to `bind`, other than that `bind` only creates a constructable function if it is called on a constructable function. As for why the method definition syntax does not create a constructor, see the duplicates.

Comment: `ask` is a method. It should be **called** on `workshop`, as a method, not be used with `new` as a constructor.